# How can I set a timer to 30 seconds and have it restart at 0.0 seconds?

Tags: swift, xcode, timer, nstimer

I am just trying a little side project. I want the user to be able to select one of 3 time options. If you select 30 seconds a timer will run for 30 seconds or 10 seconds etc, if you choice that time. Once time runs out I want it to restart back to the selected time when the timer hits 0.0

My code works for anything up till 18 seconds. If you set it to 19 or higher it does not work. I have no idea at this point why it works up till 18.. Any help would be amazing.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ChangeTime: UILabel!

var defaultTime = 0.0
var timer = Timer()

//buttons
@IBAction func ten(_ sender: UIButton) {
    ChangeTime.text = "10"
    timerLabel.text = ChangeTime.text
}
@IBAction func thirty(_ sender: UIButton) {
    ChangeTime.text = "30"
    timerLabel.text = ChangeTime.text
}
@IBAction func seven(_ sender: UIButton) {
    ChangeTime.text = "7"
    timerLabel.text = ChangeTime.text
}

@IBAction func startTimerBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    startTimerFunc()
}

func startTimerFunc() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.action), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    defaultTime = Double(Int(ChangeTime.text!)!)
}

@objc func action() {

    if timerLabel.text == "0.0" {
        timer.invalidate()
        defaultTime = 10
        startTimerFunc()
    }

    defaultTime -= 0.1
    timerLabel.text = String(format: "%.1f", defaultTime)
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to convert it to double ad then check like this

```
   @objc func action() {

        guard let unwrapString = timerLabel.text else { return  }
        let doubleValue = Double(unwrapString)



        if doubleValue == 0.0 {
            timer.invalidate()
            defaultTime = 10
            startTimerFunc()
        }

        defaultTime -= 0.1
        timerLabel.text = String(format: "%.1f", defaultTime)


}
```

Comment: You can skip the typecast to `NSString`, just use `let intValue = Double(unwrapString)`. And to avoid confusion, I would name that `doubleValue` instead of `intValue`.